# Find the linear maps that preserve this bilinear form.

Tags: linear-transformations, bilinear-form

This time I want to know which linear maps are the ones that preserve the following bilinear form:

$$\beta(x,y)=2(x_1y_1-x_2y_2)$$

and they give as a hint the matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
cosh&sinh\\-sinh&cosh
\end{pmatrix}$$

then when I multiply this matrix by the one generated by the bilinear form, this is:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2&0\\0&-2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
cosh&sinh\\-sinh&cosh
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then I get a matrix that has the same shape as the one of the bilinear form, but I think this is not preservation, so Can someone help me with this problem please? (I have tried to compute the determinants but I think this has nothing to do with the bilinear form)

Thanks a ot in advance :).

Comment: Either the formula for $\beta$ or the matrix is wrong. Is the second term negative?

Comment: Yes , I hace wrote it like un the post , and the teacher wrote it like that :( what can be done  ?

Comment: I have edited my post :)

Comment: Think about the definition of "form-preserving": $\beta(Ax, Ay)=\beta(x, y)$.

Comment: Where A is the transformation right ?

Comment: I am here in the discussion :)

Comment: Yes I am sure of it, the teacher wrote that matrix in the blackboard :)

Answer (score 1):

Under the linear transformation $x\to Ax$ we have

$$x = \left(\matrix{x_1\\x_2}\right) \to \left(\matrix{A_{11}x_1 + A_{12}x_2\\A_{21}x_1 + A_{22}x_2}\right)$$

so the bi-linear form transforms as

$$x_1y_1-x_2y_2 \to (A_{11}x_1 + A_{12}x_2)(A_{11}y_1 + A_{12}y_2) - (A_{21}x_1 + A_{22}x_2)(A_{21}y_1 + A_{22}y_2)$$

From this we see that the form is preserved iff
$$\matrix{A_{11}^2-A_{21}^2 &= 1\\A_{22}^2-A_{12}^2 &= 1\\A_{11}A_{12}-A_{21}A_{22} &= 0}$$

Since $A_{11}^2,A_{22}^2\geq 1$ we can take $A_{11}=\epsilon_{11}\cosh\alpha$ and $A_{22} = \epsilon_{22}\cosh\beta$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ and where $\epsilon_{ij}=\pm 1$. The identity $\cosh^2(x) - \sinh^2(x) = 1$ applied to the first two equations determines $A_{12}$ and $A_{21}$ (up to a sign) and the final equation fixes $\alpha=\pm\beta$ and gives a relation between the allowed combinations of signs $\epsilon_{ij}$.

---

Any solution $A$ can be written on one of the four following forms:

$$\left\{\pm\left(\matrix{+c & +s\\ +s & +c}\right),~~~\pm\left(\matrix{+c & +s\\ -s & -c}\right)\right\}$$
where $s=\sinh(\alpha)$ and $c=\cosh(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So the transformations that those requirements (the ones you posted in with the A's) are the good ones right?

Comment: @user162343 If you solve the system you will find that there are several solutions (all on the same basic form as you have in your question) that only differ with the signs of the coefficients. However the particular sign you have in the question is *not* a solution.

Comment: Right, so it is done, correct?

Comment: Ok, may be my professor had a typo :) there